# How to generated blurDataUrl in next js for a remote image?

Tags: reactjs, image, webpack, next.js

In my next js i'm loading an image. but to make it really interesting i need to load the image with some blur. in order to use blur first i must have a blurhash for the image i'm loading and convert that hash to `blurDataUrl` so that next js can understand.

but i'm not generating blurhash while uploading and my fetched image has none. so the only option i got is to generate blurDataUrl while fetching. i've used `lqip-modern` package but it throw an error throughout the whole app after installing it.

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

i thought this could be fixed by providing global image loader in `next.config` for the image and provide a custom loader. but this didn't work either. i'm fetching my images from firebase storage.

Does anyone know how to generate blurDataUrl for a remote images or generate blurhash while uploading?